# nginx rewrite excluding specifc location or directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

According to documentation, Nginx is not flexible for NOT matching a regular expression. How to rewrite and remove `.php` extension except specific location or directory ?

Rules to rewrite and redirect .php extenstion. It is working

```
location ~ .php {
    rewrite ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php break;
}
```

Here further condition applied - rewrite all php files **except** in `scuredb`

```
location ~ .php(?!(/scuredb)) { // but still scuredb/index.php - redirecting to index
```

Comment: Your negative assertion matches `/index.php/scuredb`. Try: `location ~ ^(?!(/scuredb)).*\.php`